# android insert events into own mobile calendar

Tags: android

I have copied this code sample, but I don't know the format expected for `final String eventStartDate`. Can anyone give me an example of that. i.e. `'%Y/%m/%d'`?

```
public class CreateCalenderEvent 
{
  public static void addToCalendar(Context oContext, final String title, final String eventStartDate) 
  {
    String eventUriString = null;

    long startDate = new Date(eventStartDate).getTime();
    long endDate = new Date(eventStartDate).getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60; // For next 1hr
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

    ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) 
    {
        eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";

        eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1); 
        eventValues.put("title", title);
        eventValues.put("description", "");
        eventValues.put("eventLocation", "");

        eventValues.put("dtstart", startDate); 
        eventValues.put("dtend", endDate);

        eventValues.put("eventStatus", "");
        eventValues.put("visibility", 3); 
        eventValues.put("transparency", 0);
        eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1);

        Uri eventUri = oContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
        long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());

        String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";

        ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

        reminderValues.put("event_id", eventID);
        reminderValues.put("minutes", 5);
        reminderValues.put("method", 1);

        oContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);

    } 
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 )
    {
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startDate);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endDate);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "");
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 3);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

        oContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, eventValues);
    }

    Toast.makeText(oContext, "Event Created on : " + startDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use many formats if you want date only then **yyyy-MM-dd** can work nice.
For Date-Time use **yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SS** 24 Hrs format